# Add columns to dataframe K-Mean - Python

Tags: python, pandas, k-means, knn

I am using this code to do K-Mean analysis on a dataframe. I am able to plot the resulting dataframe but I want to add the original dataframe columns to it. My python is not brilliant so it might be simple but I keep getting invalid syntax for whatever I try.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples

df2 = df[['x','y']]
k = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
assignedClusters = k.fit(df2)

sh_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'silhouette': silhouette_samples(df2, assignedClusters.labels_),
        'cluster': assignedClusters.labels_
    }
)
```

The `sh_df` has two columns, "silhouette" and "clusters" values.  I want this df to also include the x and y values from my original df. Is this possible and can someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do

```
sh_df['x'] = df2['x']
sh_df['y'] = df2['y']
```

assuming the `sh_df` and `my_df` are ordered the same. That is, that the nth row of one dataframe corresponds to the nth row of the other.

Comment: is there a way to find out if both df's are in order? Any way of adding it to this line output_df = pd.DataFrame({'silhouette':silhouette_samples(my_df, 
Clusters.labels_), 'clusters':Clusters.labels_})

Comment: This doesn't work, it allows me to run the code, but the values are nan for the new columns

Comment: Can you show all of your code, please? For example, I assume you're using scikit learn for KMeans, but that's only a guess.

Comment: Where does df in the first line my_df = df[['x', 'y']] come from?

Comment: df is another df with more columns.

Comment: Are you certain that df2['x'] and df2['y'] aren't actuall all NaNs? Can you include results of df.head() in the question so we can see a bit what that looks like?

Comment: ...yeah, this is the effect of answering half baked questions. I'd recommend being a little wary of questions like this. Save yourself the headache and answer well asked questions only. See [answer].

Comment: @Metropolis Thanks for all the help, I inspected both data sets and the issue was that my original dataframe had a Index column, It all worked fine after I resetted the index.